# React Redux thunk form validation

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, react-hook-form

I am using React and Redux thunk for async function something like that.

```
//actions.js
export const fetchData = () => async(dispatch) => {
    dispatch({type:'FETCHING_DATA'})

    try {
        const response = await Axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
        
        dispatch({type:'FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS', payload: response.data})

    } catch(error) {
        dispatch({type:'FETCH_DATA_FAILURE', error})
    }
}
```

```
//reducer.js

const initState = {
    items: [],
    loading: false,
    error: null
}

const dataReducer = (state=initState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "FETCHING_DATA":
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true,
                error: null
            }
        case "FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS":
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                items: action.payload
            }
        case "FETCH_DATA_FAILURE":
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                error: action.error
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

```
//RandomComponent.js

    const state = useSelector((state) => state)

    useEffect(()=> {
        dispatch(fetchPosts())
    }, [])

    const renderPosts = () => {
        if (state.loading) {
            return <h1>loading</h1>
        }

        return state.items.map(element => {
            return <h1>{element.title}</h1>
        })
    }
```

It works nice. But now with forms I am little bit stuck.
For example when i have form in modal window, so i want to wait for the response. E.g. create record. If record was succesfully created close modal window, but when was some error on the API side let modal window open for other processing.
I think that it should something like this

```
const submitForm = async(data) => {
  await dispatch(createRecord(data));
  ...
  if(recordWasCreated){
     closeModal()
  }
}
```

and I don't know how to proceed. Thank for some tips.

Comment: Hi @Mormen, Can you upvote my answer since you accepted it as the best answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post your full code on codesandbox or github. In general, though waiting for dispatch is not required. The way you are closing the modal is not correct. Your modal's visibility should be controlled by state. E.g. you can set a flag in state once the record is created and then use it like below

```
<Modal show={!state.recordCreated}/>
```